# How to split a text file into multiple fragments with specific number of lines in each fragment?

Tags: apache-camel

This is a simplified solution for my requirement:

The number of lines in each fragment is known only after some processing.

Also I need to write the number of lines in each fragment file as a header for these fragment files. I have various solutions that are close but I cannot figure out how to do this fully.

I am running around in circles. Help.

Answer (score 0):

If using expressions allowed for your case then you can use any expression language supported by camel (like groovy, mvel etc.) to do actual splitting.

http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html